# Multiple PuTTY windows/consoles using one SSH connection

Tags: windows, terminal, putty, console, multiple-instances

In any major OS, you can open multiple terminal connections. Is this possible using PuTTY?

To be clear, I do not mean opening up a console session and logging into remote equipment. Then starting a new PuTTY window (2nd) and logging into the same equipment again.

Once PuTTY is opened and logged into whatever equipment, opening another window that is connected using the established connection.

Answer (score 2):

PuTTY supports that too. It just needs to be enabled. The feature is called "connection sharing".

To enable it:

- go to *Connection > SSH* page
- locate ["Sharing an SSH connection between PuTTY tools"](https://the.earth.li/~sgtatham/putty/latest/htmldoc/Chapter4.html#config-ssh-sharing) box
- and check *"Share SSH connection if possible"*

The option needs to be enabled both in the "upstream" and "downstream" instance.